# Button function for all fetch row

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am doing project for my university. I create a page where user can send friend request. Here I fetch data from another table and put button for each row data.

My problem is that when one button click other row button also was change to friend request. I need a solution for it.

How to make one add friend request button is equal to one row id and how to avoid other button affected whenever click particular row.

My code is included below. I hope you guys will help me. Thanks in advance.

```php
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['myid'];

$mysqli=new MySQLi('127.0.0.1','root','','learning_malaysia');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tutor_register INNER JOIN tutorskill ON tutor_register.register_ID = tutorskill.register_ID ORDER BY 
tutor_register.register_ID='".$_SESSION['myid']."'desc";
$result= mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{      


         $register_ID=$row["register_ID"];
            $username = $row['username'];
            $profile = $row['profile'];
            $email = $row['email'];
            $address=$row['address'];
            $gender=$row['gender'];
             $main_subject=$row["main_subject"];
             $subject_add=$row["subject_add"];
            $rate_main=$row["rate_main"];
            $rate_add=$row["rate_add"];
            $qualification=$row["qualification"];
            ?>
            <table><form method="post">
            <tr class="border_bottom">
            <td height="230"><img src='<?php echo $profile;?>'width="200" height="200"/>&nbsp;</td><td><td></td></td>
 <?php 
         if($register_ID == $_SESSION['myid']){
                ?>
                <td><label>Your Profile</label></td>
                <?php
            } else {
                ?> 
                 <form method="post">
                 <td><button class='friendBtn unfriend'  name="" data-type="unfriend">Unfriend</button>
                 <input type="hidden" name="id"  value="<?php echo $row['register_ID'];?>" />  
                 <input type="submit" name="addfriend" data-type='addfriend' id="addfriend" value="<?php 
                     if($_SESSION['status'] == 'yes'){ 
                     echo 'Request Sent';
                     }
                     else { 
                     echo 'Addfriend';}
                     ?>" data-uid=<?php echo $row['register_ID'];?>/></td> </form>     
<?php
            }
}
?>
 </tr>
</div>
</table>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['id']) ) {
$user_id = $_SESSION['myid'];
$friend_id = $_POST['id'];
$sql="INSERT INTO friends(user_id,status,friend_id)" ."VALUES('$user_id','yes','$friend_id') ";

            if($mysqli->query($sql)=== true) {
                          $_SESSION['status']="yes";
                          $_SESSION['id']=$row['id'];
            } else {}
                              }
                }


?> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your html is invalid - mismatched open and close tags, tags straddling illegally and the sql is vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, I understand this is your first question, but it doesn't meet the standard quality expected, please read stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to have some guidance. For instance you don't provide the error you actually get.

Comment: i put html tag  but here i forget to paste it. sorry for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace the following block in your code:

```
<input type="submit" name="addfriend" data-type='addfriend' id="addfriend" value="<?php 
         if($_SESSION['status'] == 'yes'){ 
         echo 'Request Sent';
         }
         else { 
         echo 'Addfriend';}
         ?>" data-uid=<?php echo $row['register_ID'];?>/>
```

With the one mentioned below. This will solve your problem.

```
<input type="submit" name="addfriend" data-type='addfriend' id="addfriend" value="<?php 
         if($_SESSION['status'] == 'yes' && $row['register_ID']==$_SESSION['id']){ 
         echo 'Request Sent';
         }
         else { 
         echo 'Addfriend';}
         ?>" data-uid=<?php echo $row['register_ID'];?>/>
```

Comment: thanks Alot and sorry for late rply..its work for me